# View data save -without any button click

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have a view which has some data entered by user. Once user moves out of this View, data in it should get automatically saved. We don't have any save button to get any click event. Please advise, how to capture View event once we dont have any save button

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a saveonshow attribute that you can set to true to automatically save when you leave that view and return to the previous view.